# Insert string with null character intermediate in oracle table

Tags: java, null, char

I have a variable of type StringBuffer which has null character i.e. '\0' intermediate. I can print the variable correctly with the null character. But when I try to insert this variable in Oracle table, I cannot able to insert whole StringBuffer variable; only the part before '\0'. The column in which i am inserting this variable has data type as varchar2(50).
I don't know why its happening. May be oracle doesn't allow string with null term chars intermediate. I know that once '\0' encountered in string, its treated as end of string. 
Here is what I tried

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("Vishal,");
buffer.append("Tavande,");
buffer.append('\0');
buffer.append("Kolhapur");
System.out.println(buffer);
```

This shows me output as "Vishal,Tavande, Kolhapur". When I put this buffer in table I can see only "Vishal,Tavande,"

Please tell me how to insert a string with null char intermediate.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why are you trying to deliberately put a null in there?

Comment: I want to put variable values from structure into a string/StringBuffer variable for auditing purpose

Comment: Normally, if you have null in your structure - would it come as actual null - or as '\0'? I'm just wondering why you try to force '\0'...

Comment: That's because the thing that is displaying your results is stopping at the null. Didn't you mean \u0000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, In Oracle Varchar2 behaves like a NULL-terminated STRING.

You can search in this document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci03typ.htm

So, try some different character instead of `\0`

Comment: What can I try instead of \0 ?

Comment: Well, its depend on your logic.